# React - Getting content from array within embedded component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to break my app down into more easily manageable components. Because of this I have a component called `LatestProducts` and then within that component I am mapping an array to a child component, `LatestProduct`. How can I make it so that the child component can use the data from the parent component?

**LatestProducts:**

```
import LatestProduct from '../LatestProduct';

class LatestProducts extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            LatestProducts: []
        }
    }

    ...

    render() {
        const LatestProducts = this.state.LatestProducts;
        return (
            <div className="row">
                {LatestProducts.map((product, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index} className="product"><LatestProduct /></div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    };
};
```

**LatestProduct:**

```
class LatestPost extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <article className="product-container">
                <h2>{product.title}</h2>
            </article>
        );
    };
};
```

This obviously returns an error because `product` is undefined on the `LatestProduct` component. How can I pass that down to the child component?

Comment: Bakhtiiar has the answer, but beyond that definitely look into some explanations/tutorials/articles of what props are and how they work, they're one of the fundamentals of React

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it down through `props`.

What I would do is the following in the `LatestProducts` component:

```
LatestProducts.map((product, index) => {
    return <div key={index} className="product"><LatestProduct product={product} /></div>
})
```

And access it in your `LatestPost` component as follows:

```
 class LatestPost extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return <article className="product-container">
            <h2>{this.props.product.title}</h2>
        </article>
    };
};
```

Suggested documentation to read is [Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) from React site.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Do not arbitrarily put props in state.  That's asking for trouble.

Comment: Well hello again, and thank you once again, that worked swimmingly! And thank you for the reading material, definitely going to look it over before I continue development!

Answer (score 1):

use `props`

```
<LatestProduct product={product}/>
```